# The member "IsChecked" is not recognized or is not accessible. Can anyone help me solve this issue

Tags: wpf, xaml

```
    <Image Source="C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\GUI\Lektion 13\WpfApp1\12-LightOn.bmp" Canvas.Left="53" Canvas.Top="81" Name="LightOn"></Image>

    <ToggleButton Height="47" Canvas.Left="320" Canvas.Top="228" Width="47">
        <ToggleButton.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource LightOn}"/>
            </Trigger>
        </ToggleButton.Triggers>
    </ToggleButton>
```

the problem is at  it cant recognize "IsChecked" for some reason and this code is only allowed to be written in the XAML window so i cant use eventhandlers in the mainwindow.cs. I cant figure out why i cant change the property to content. All of this code is places in a canvas

Answer (score 1):

The `FrameworkElement.Triggers` collection can only contain EventTriggers. Use a Style instead:

```
<ToggleButton Height="47" Canvas.Left="320" Canvas.Top="228" Width="47">
    <ToggleButton.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ToggleButton">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{DynamicResource LightOn}"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ToggleButton.Style>
</ToggleButton>
```